# how to use LINQ query?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a input string,

```
string str1 = "aabcccabdfa";
```

I want to count the occurrence of each character and put it next to that character. So I need to output result as `"a4b2c3d1f1"`. How can i achieve this with LINQ?

I try with "Dictionary" to do that, but not able to do that.

Thanks,

Comment: What happens between the input and output?

Comment: This is probably homework.  There is a good chance that your professor will use Google to find students that copied the assignment onto a Q&A forum and turned in the answer they got verbatim.  Also, you will not learn if you don't at least show *specifically* what you tried and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: hopefully the OP can understand the answer especially when it comes to having to maintain their own code.. for future updates..

Comment: What is the problem in question why so many downvotes

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It shows no effort.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
string str1 = "aabcccabdfa";
string.Concat(str1.GroupBy(c => c).OrderBy(c => c.Key).Select(c => c.Key.ToString() + c.Count()));
```

Comment: The .ToCharArray() is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: @tnw Then The OPs teacher will join SO! :)

Comment: You're right, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str1 = "aabcccabdfa";
var result=string.Concat(str1.GroupBy(a=>a)
  .Select(a=>a.Key.ToString()+a.Count().ToString()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string str1 = "aabcccabdfa";
var output = "";
str1.ToArray().Distinct().ToList().ForEach(x => output += x + (str1.Count(f => f == x).ToString()));
```